# PopupWindow animation crashes device

Tags: android, animation

I have been trying to run a simple scale animation on my PopupWindow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="0"
    android:pivotY="0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Everything is working perfectly fine until I change duration to about 3000. From that point on, my Galaxy S5 running on Android 5.0(API 21) just hangs for couple of seconds and then crashes.
Here is the method that deals with PopupWindow.

```
if(noConnectionPopup == null || !noConnectionPopup.isShowing()) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_connection_popup, null);
        noConnectionPopup = new PopupWindow(view,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(int)(toolbar.getHeight() * 1.5),false);
        noConnectionPopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
        noConnectionPopup.showAsDropDown(toolbar, 0, 0);
    }
```

Here is the Animation style resource.

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/no_connection_popup_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/no_connection_popup_hide</item>
</style>
```

And here is the layout being inflated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
    android:text="No connection"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried probably everything now. It seems that the problem is leaving the XScale unchanged, but I still cant understand why it works with smaller durations. In emulator it works with any duration. What is the problem and is there anything I could do?

Comment: please add the crash log

Comment: No Java Exception gets thrown. Nothing on logcat, no stack trace. It just freezes and then my device restarts.

Comment: Dropped PopupWindow, added view directly to layout. Works fine now.